# Game I thought was called "By Popular Demand"

Tags: identify-this-game

Where I work we have a quiz every Friday.  I'm trying to find a quiz like game we can do by email instead whilst many of us are working remotely.

I'm trying to find online rules to a game that I *thought* was called By Popular Demand.  I recall playing it online in the early 2000's I think on the now defunct psychozine website.

The rules as I recall:

- Players are given categories.
- They write down a (correct) answer in each category
- They score 1 point for every one else who gave same answers.
- Highest overall scores win

There was also an opposite game that I thought was called By Unpopular Demand.  Same rules except lowest score wins.

Have I dreamt these or are they real games known by a different name?  I'm trying to find an online rules link to send with the game tomorrow or I will just write rules out for my fictional game.

Comment: This sounds kind of like Scategories, except in Scategories you earn points for unique answers, not shared answers.  Also, there's an alphabet die in Scategories.

Comment: Seems potentially related to *Family Feud*...

Comment: Also sounds like *Hive Mind* and at least one unpublished prototype ("Sheep"?) I've played

Comment: It is similar to the UK Gameshow Pointless too; I suspect there are lots of games based on the concept and if I were the original poster, I’d just make up my own rules...

Comment: I played it on a website in early 2000's so what I played had a name.  I think the rules are so simple as defined I can just use as is and not need to edit rules

Comment: The problem is if you played it on a website 20 years ago, it may have just been a creation of someone on that website, perhaps based on Scattergories as Lupus suggests, rather than being a published product - and there are so many game websites that have died over the years, even more now that flash is being fully retired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Popular Demand is still played in games 'zine Variable Pig (and possibly others) and their rules are online at https://www.variablepig.org/rules/bypop.html